# How to get number of possibilities in equation?

Tags: combinatorics

We have 10 the same balls and 4 different cells.

How to get number of possibilities to throw these balls in cells the way that in cell will be 3 balls?

I see there are a few possible ways when we have 3 balls in first cell, when we have 3 balls in second cell and so on, then we have an option when we have 3 balls in first cell and 3 in second, then 3 balls in second and 3 in third and so on and then also we have an option when we have 3 balls in first, second and third cell and in last cell just one ball.

So, question is: how many possible ways to throw these balls in cells? (at least one cell should contain 3 balls)

Comment: Search for stars and bars on google

Comment: You can also count the same number by subtracting the number of possibilities with each cell having at most 2 balls from the total number of possibilities.

Comment: Also note that if you put at most 2 balls in each cell, then you can't put all of them 10, since 2*4 is 8. Hence the problem is trivial if you must put all of them, since there will be a cell with at least 3 balls.